Facebook page reels video upload facing error "message": "(#200) subject does not have permission to post videos on this target", "code": 200
Facebook page reels video upload with API facing issue
{ "error": { "message": "(#200) subject does not have permission to post videos on this target", "type": "oauthexception", "code": 200, "fbtrace_id": "afayglg374lfu4ml65zprso" } }
Note: upload my own page
Remove Facebook app and reconnect again and allow all permission requirement documentation,
One time everything is perfect but suddenly show this error then I try create new app and try again but still show this problem and also change the my machine(PC) use new Facebook account and new page but You still show this problem
